# showing 32th bit of 1 as set

Tags: c++, bit

when i was counting the number of set bits in a number, i gave input as 1
and found ans was 2,
when i debug the program the 32 bit was set,how can it be possible?
Because only first bit is set in 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        int ans = 0;
        for(int i=32;i>=0;i--){
            if(n&(1<<i))
               ans++;
        }
        cout<<ans<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i<<32 is probably 1 again, as the variable "rolls over". Try printing out 1<<32 and check what happens.

Comment: Try starting the loop from 31 instead of 32.

Comment: You are printing 33 bits. From 32 to 0 inclusively.

Comment: Shifting by `>=` the number of bits in the int is undefined behavior.

Comment: Perhaps it's a machine with 32-bit `int`?  If so, `1<<32` causes Undefined Behaviour.  Try using a different type (e.g. `std::uint_fast64_t`).

Comment: in one what we call to first set bit ,is it 0 or 1 ,I am confused here because 2^0 is 1
so what we should call it as 0th bit or first bit .

Comment: its the 1st bit with index `0`. Indexing always starts at `0`, such that the n-th element has index `n-1`

Answer (score 0):

32 till 0 both inclusive are 33 bits in total, you are off by one here:

```
for(int i=32;i>=0;i--){
     if(n&(1<<i)) ans++;
     std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

I added a `cout` that lets you verify that. Instead you should start the loop at 31, ie

```
for(int i=31;i>=0;i--){
```

Note that [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) comes extremely handy whenever you care about the bit-representation of numbers.

PS: Actually I wonder why you have the loop reversed. This kind of problems are less likely when you write the more common `for (int i=0;i<32;++i)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the first iteration. You shift the number 1 by 32 bits, which on my machine results in a 1. Since int are probably 32 bit, that's not defined behavior.

```
if(n&(1<<32)!=0)
```

The fix is to start your for from 31.

```
for(int i=31;i>=0;i--)
```